# check if startTime and endTimer are between two times

Tags: java, spring, time, datetime-comparison

I am working on a project for booking venues. The aim is to not allow the booking if the venue is already booking during this period

```
 if (!alreadyBookedSet.isEmpty()) {

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        logger.debug("Check if the venue is already booked on this date" + booking.getBookingDate());
        for (Booking alreadyBooked : alreadyBookedSet) {
            String bookingDate = alreadyBooked.getBookingDate();

            if (bookingDate.equals(booking.getBookingDate())) {

                String alreadyBookedTimeStart = alreadyBooked.getTimeStart();
                Date alreadyBookedTimeStartDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(alreadyBookedTimeStart);

                String alreaydBookedTimeEnd = alreadyBooked.getTimeEnd();
                Date alreaydBookedTimeEndDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(alreaydBookedTimeEnd);


                String bookingTimeStart = booking.getTimeStart();
                Date bookingTimeStartDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(bookingTimeStart);

                String bookingTimeEnd = booking.getTimeEnd();
                Date bookingTimeEndDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(bookingTimeEnd);

                if (!bookingTimeStartDate.before(alreadyBookedTimeStartDate) && !bookingTimeEndDate.after(alreaydBookedTimeEndDate)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have an issue when the venue is already booked from 2:00 PM to 3:00 PM and we want to book it from 1:00 PM to 3:00 PM. This returns that the venue is not already booked which it is.

Is there a way to solve all the probabilities a between method in java?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Could you adapt the answers to this question to answer yours? [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: Don’t keep start and end times as strings in your booking objects. Keep them as `LocalTime` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there are overlaps, so the logic should be

```
if(!bookingTimeStartDate.before(alreadyBookedTimeStartDate) && 
!bookingTimeStartDate.after(alreaydBookedTimeEndDate) || 
!bookingTimeEndDate.before(alreaydBookedTimeStartDate) && 
!bookingTimeEndDate.after(alreaydBookedTimeEndDate))
```

This is the correct logic since if either of the times are not before the start and after the end, they must be in between and are therefore, overlapping.

Comment: It does not really work in this case:
 20/11/2019 |   9:00:00 AM  |   8:00:00 AM    and | 20/11/2019   11:00:00 AM |   10:00:00 AM |  are already booked for the same venue. I can not book the same venue Date='20/11/2019', timeStart=' 9:00:00 AM', timeEnd=' 10:00:00 AM'

Comment: You'd have to add a check to see if they're equal if you also want to allow back to back bookings.

Comment: It’s overly complicated and it isn’t correct.